# Standard Connector for Audio Line Out

Tags: audio, rca

I have to give audio Line Out in my project. I don't know which connector I have to give this out. I have found that in PC, 3.5mm Jack is used for line in and line out. Also found that RCA jacks have been used for line out in other equipment. I want to know what is the standard connector for LINe out interface. 
Also please suggest whether 3.5mm headphone jacks can be used for Line Out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, there is no 'default'.

There are many more types:

- 5 pin DIN (very old, obsoleted by RCA); mono or stereo per connector

[image]

- RCA (2 different plugs for stereo), mostly obsoleted by 3.5 or 6.3mm jack plugs; mono per connector

[image]

- Jack plugs (3.5mm used in most consumer devices), 6.3mm for more high-end devices (in general), mono or stereo per connector

[image]

- XLR plugs (mostly 2 plugs for stereo), used by 'professional' sound equipment; mostly mono per connector. Also these plugs have the advantage to 'lock' themselves.

[image]

All of the above can be used for input or output audio.

Comment: Can I use 3.5mm headphone jack for Line out

Comment: Yes, in a computer it is used (for e.g. line audio out), or the audio output of a mobile phone or MP3 player.

Comment: "I have found that in PC, 3.5mm Jack is used for line in and line out" - so you already know the answer to your question. Or do you think there's a difference between a "3.5mm Jack" and a "3.5mm headphone jack"? There isn't.